# Service failing to correctly return status code to UI

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc

Maybe this is silly question but I'm trying to learn Spring MVC and I have everything working except for the exceptions.  So I have a simple form application where the user can register, if the user already exists I'd like to send an error code to the UI so that it knows why it failed.  Heres my code:

```
  @ResponseBody
  @PostMapping("users")
  public ResponseEntity addUser(@RequestBody User user) {
    List<User> users = usersService.addUser(user);
    if(users == null) return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.EXPECTATION_FAILED);
    else return new ResponseEntity<>(users, HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);
  }
```

It works fine, as in it returns a status code to the UI but the exception returns it in this string format:

```
Error: Request failed with status code 417
    at createError (createError.js:17)
    at settle (settle.js:19)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:69)
```

The log above is from a console log from the UI, right after the catch below:

```
function register(user) { 
    return dispatch => {
        axios.post(`${BASE_URL}/users`, user).then((response) => {
            console.log(response);
            dispatch(resetError());
            dispatch(success(user));
        }).catch((e) => {
            console.log('e', e);
            dispatch(error(e.status));
        })
    };
    function success(user) { return { type: userConstants.REGISTER, payload: user } };
};
```

Funny enough it actually prints exactly what I'm looking for if the http call succeeds.  Here's what it prints on the happy path of the promise (ACCEPTED):

[image]

Notice that it has a status property.  I'd very much not like to parse a string on the UI side just to get the error code from the service.  Why is the response object different? The only thing I've changed is the status code.  How can I make the error status give the UI a nice object instead of a string?

If you'd like to pull the branch here is the URL: https://github.com/MatTaNg/react-form

The code snippets are in the UsersResource file

Comment: Have you tried throwing UserAlreadyExistException when user==null and using @ControllerAdvice to handle global exception.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of console.log('e', e) try console.log('e', e.response.status).

Source:
https://github.com/axios/axios#handling-errors